# Можно ли с Windows запускать flutter приложение подключив Iphone

Tags: windows, ios, flutter

Знаю что можно запускать Flutter проект подключив к пк телефон на базе андройд. Вроде как можно тоже самое делать если подключить к MAC айфон,но могу ли я разрабатывая на винде подключить айфон и на нем уже запускать приложение?
Есть макбук,но спустя 4 часа дико греется и тормозит и на десктопе мне привычнее писать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, не можете. У Apple такая политика, вы можете разрабатывать только на маке. Единственный вариант - это собирать на какой-нибудь удаленной машине. Но это костыль, в любой момент что-нибудь отвалится. Для нормальной разработки без мака никак.

А вот для андроида можете разрабатывать где угодно. Поэтому, предпочтительнее будет мак. Т.к. можно разрабатывать сразу на обе системы.

Comment: да вот самое обидное что мой mac air не вывозит
за 3-4 часа эмуляции и он умирает
Спасибо за ответ)

Comment: А виртуалка или некий "хакинтош" больше не вывозят?

Comment: @muri_top Без реального устройства тоже будет тяжело. Некоторые вещи на эмуляторе не тестируются. Поэтому iPhone я бы тоже приобрел, можно старенький.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov смотря какой. У меня был макмини 12 года. Так вот туда новый Xcode уже не ставился, соответственно разработка невозможна. Да и в целом Xcode стал очень требователен.

Comment: @Dinario Мне сложно утверждать что-то голословно: последний раз я сталкивался с разработкой под Apple в 2018 году. Тогда виртуалка сработала идеально